# Secure way to launch lightdm/xorg/xfree86 from console startup

Tags: boot, xorg, lightdm, console, runlevel

If I launch Ubuntu in console mode, i.e.:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro text
```

And then [issuing the remaining commands necessary to boot to command line](https://linux.m2osw.com/boot-command-line-console-ubuntu-1604):

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

I can successfully boot to command-line rather than starting the window manager. However, if I start a window manager, either via `sudo service lightdm start` or `sudo startx`, and then lock the screen, or even "log out", all I need to do is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I'm now back to my original boot console, where I've already logged in. This means, that if I am to boot to the console, it is no longer secure to use the window manager unless I reboot the system, or at least exit the window manager, and log out a second time.

Is there a secure way to have a crash/close of the window manager (i.e. `lightdm`) trigger a logout of the console session that launched it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just exit the console after starting X?

```bsh
sudo service lightdm start && exit
nohup startx; exit   # send startx to background and exit
```

Note the problem you describe would be the same as when you login into any other TTY. Simply switching to some TTY does not (and IMO should not) log you out of other TTYs where you're logged in.

Comment: Good point. I still contend that the window manager being "locked" should provide some meaningful sense of security though.